# Symfony 2 "findBy" a mapped entity parameter into controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm new with Symfony2 and i would like to know whether there is a way to use the "findBy" with a param which is present only in a mapped entity.

This is my snippet controller:

```
$prods = $em->getRepository('EcommerceProductBundle:ProductData')
    ->findBy(array(
        'product_id'=>46
    ));
```

It works good but if i try to add another element to the array, which is present in a mapped entity, it get (rightly) this error

```
Unrecognized field: ProductImage.is_visible
```

What i would like to do, is just to know wehether i can use the "filterBy" with a mapped element of the entity ProductData.

I'm in wrong but this is my idea:

```
->findBy(array(
  'product_id'=>46,
  'ProductImage.is_visible'=>1    
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, you need to write a custom method in the repository with a join clause.

The findBy method just add a where clause on the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as i know. Just add this custom method to your repository:

```
public function findByIdAndVisibleImage($id)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
        ->lefJoin("product.image","i")
        ->where("product.product_id = :id")
        ->andWhere("i.is_visible = 1") 
        ->setParameter("id", $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, i've already written a customised query but i wonted to know if it's possible without it.
Thanks anyway.